# WPF - customize view using triggers in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, triggers, windows-phone-8.1

I want to customize my view in Windows Phone 8.1 app (WPF). In my desktop project I used something like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrueValue}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTrueValue}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately *Style.Triggers* is not recognized.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Triggers are not supported in Windows Phone xaml. Look up [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Phone does not use WPF. You can use either Windows Phone Silverlight or Windows Phone Runtime code. All three of these environments use Xaml, but the exact classes available are different.

While there isn't direct support for Triggers, the [Behaviors SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn457340.aspx) defines a DataTrigger behavior that works similarly for Windows Runtime apps. Behaviors are included in Blend's asset pane and can be set up visually in its designer.

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"


<Grid>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsTrueValue}" Value="True">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsTrueValue}" Value="False">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

As Vlad suggests, you can also use a VisualStateManager rather than directly setting the Visibility property. You can use a DataTriggerBehavior to trigger a GoToStateAction.

Also note that Visibility.Hidden isn't valid for either Windows Phone Runtime or Windows Phone Silverlight. Both allow the Visible and Collapsed options.